# git tries to upload deleted file that is not staged

Tags: git, github, unstage

I had a file `F` that exceeded 100 MB limit that I tried to push. So the push failed. I then removed the file, because it could not be pushed and assumed I needed to do `add . ; commit` and `push` again. In the auto generated commit it said `deleted file F`. Upon `push` it still tried to upload that file. Well ok, so I figured I need to unstage `F`. SO I did `reset F`. I got the message `fatal: ambiguous argument 'out': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.` No idea what that meant, so I tried to make git show me the staged files `diff --cached`, but the output is empty. I am confused about the situation and how I can untangle it.

To recap the chain :

`$> git add. ; git commit`

`$> git push`

`$> remote: error: File F is 143.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

`$> rm F`

`$> git add. ; git commit`

`$> git push`

`$> remote: error: File F is 143.41 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`

`$> git diff --cached`

`$>`

Comment: You have your large file in some older commit. You need to re-write history to get rid of it. You can always inspect your local history using graphical interface provided by `gitk`. `git log --name-only` is your friend as well. Use git commit --amend` or `git reabse -i` to re-write history.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that the file is already part of the historical commit.

You need to get back to the commit and amend it:

```
# reset to previous commit but keeping content:
git reset --soft "HEAD^"
# potentially modify the tree content
# amend the old commit with the file removed:
git commit --amend
# push:
git push
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. What exactly did the first command do though? What is "HEAD^"?

Comment: @lotolmencre : that identifies the commit previous to the HEAD.